# How to create a fluid UI with interface builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to create a fluid UI with interface builder?

For example, say I have a page that has a few fields at the top, some of which are optional. Can I make some of them invisible and have the fields below move up to fill the gap?

Similarly, if I have a tableview in a page followed by a text field, can I have the tableview grow and shrink and still have the text field immediately after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do with interface builder is setting autoresizing masks.  So if your view container changes dimensions the iPhone can adjust sizes accordingly.

To answer your questions:

1: You can't accomplish the functionality directly with interface builder, You can setup your interface but then you'll have to write the logic in the controller to achieve that functionality.

2: This you can accomplish in interface builder.  You add the textField to the footerView of the tableview, and then the text field will always remain at the bottom of the tableView no matter what is displayed in your table.

[image]

Comment: I have found many code examples of adding a view to the tableview's footer, but how do you add it in interface builder?

Comment: you can just drag it from the object library into the view of the footer of the table view in IB.  If your adding a text field though it might make sense to use a UIView container and then add the text field as a subview.

Comment: I added an image of what this looks like (it says section footer right above it but its actually the tableview footer)